# Create a digital clock that updates every second in React JS - Shows some number instead of Time

Tags: reactjs

I started learning ReactJS and as part of sample project, I have to create a digital clock that updates every second. Here is my code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var currentTime = function () {
    return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    };
    this.state= {
        time: currentTime()
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Sample Data: {this.state.time}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

When I tried above code, I am getting current time. So to update time every second I updated part of code like below

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      var currentTime = function () {
          return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      };
      this.state= {
          time: setInterval(currentTime(), 1000)
      }
  }
```

Then My time display shows like "Sample Date: 2".

I found somewhat similar questions but I found those are having very complex coding.  All I am asking asking is Please let me know whats wrong with my code and any code changes required.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in the above snippet is set the reference to `setTimeout` in your state prop.

You want to update state every second you need to use `componentDidMount` and then call `setState()` like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {
this.interval = null;
currentTime() {
  return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
};
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        time: this.currentTime()
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Sample Data: {this.state.time}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({time: this.currentTime()}), 1000)
}

componentWillUnMount(){
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
}
```

It is important whenever starting interval or event listener to clear it before the component un-mounts otherwise there will be a memory leak.